# how to avoid race condition when multiple jvm reading/writing same instances of NoSQL db like mongodb?

Tags: java, multithreading, mongodb, jvm

I am running on a scenario where a NoSQL DB(MongoDB) will hold a record of success or failure status of a certain task and if a task is in failed state, my java scheduler application will read the status,retry and will try to execute the task once again and if task completes successfully, will update the DB record as 'success' state or 'fail' state if failed again.

Now the problem is, my application is deployed in two different nodes(so basically 2 different jvm) and both the nodes share the common NoSQL DB.At a certain point, one scheduler thread wakes up,read the DB and retries for failed tasks and before it completes its execution, another application thread from different node read DB record and and re-executes the task once again which override the previous successful data record update causes unexpected results. So in short, i am running through a race condition and i do not have control over NoSQL DB lock but I want to control at application level.

How do I prevent my application from reading the record which is already been  under process by another jvm thread ??

Your suggestions will be greatly appreciated.

I am using ***jongo*** library  version 1.2 and jdk 1.8

Comment: Can you update the record to say it's being processed?

Comment: Thanks @Peter for your answer. I can update the record status as 'processed' so that another thread can check the status as not 'processed' and not 'success' before reading and updating the record but drawback of that idea is that for whatever reason if mongodb goes down while the task is in processing state(resiliency test), it wont be considered for retry again even it is eligible once mongodb is up and the task will be in processing state forever. That is why i was stressing up on jvm level if there is any.

Comment: May be you would like to take a look at https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/write-operations-atomicity/

Comment: @RIPAN you can have a timestamp of when the task started and then time it out if not processed in a reasonable amount of time.

Comment: Sounds like a good idea @Peter, im gonna try that and let you know the result and thanks again.